# Formal proof for the asymptotic of a partial sum

Tags: summation, asymptotics, exponential-function

Dealing with a problem, I need to find some $f(x)$ to solve the following asymptotic when $n$ grows to infinity: $$ \frac{n}{\log(n)}\sim \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$$

I have checked with a Python program that $f(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log\log(x)}$ has almost no error when I calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}{\log\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}\right) - \frac{n}{\log(n)}$. However, I am not sure about how to prove formally why the asymptotic holds.

Here is what I have tried. [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) guarantees that, when $n$ grows to infinity, $\log(n!)\sim n\log(n) - n$. Therefore, we have that, when $n$ grows to infinity,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)=n\log(n) - \log(n!) \sim n\log(n) -n\log(n) + n \sim n$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)=n\log\log(n) - \log\log(n!) \sim n\log\log(n) -n\log\log(n) + \log (n) \sim \log (n)$$

I am not sure if the above is correct, and how to conclude the proof. Could you help me with the formal proof stating that when $n$ grows to infinity we have that $$ \frac{n}{\log(n)}\sim \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}{\log\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Noticing the Riemann sum, we obtain $1/\log(n) ~ \int_{0}^{1}f(1/x)$, so $\int_{0}^{1}f(1/x) = 0$.

Comment: @Mason thanks for your comment! Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Since we have $\frac{1}{\log(n)}\sim \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{1}{k/n})$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{1}{k/n})=\int_0^1 f(\frac 1x)dx$, we obtain $\int_0^1 f(\frac 1x)dx=0$. I think this is what the above comment meant.

Comment: Can you double check your calculation? I don't even think your formula works numerically. I did it for n=10^5, and the ration of $(RHS)*\log(n)/n$ is -66.

Comment: We cannot calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}{\log\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}\right)$, because when $k=n$ then $\log\log\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)=\log\log 1=\log 0$, which is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. All are really useful indeed. @Threeaggies I have revised my code and indeed my error measurement was wrong. However, I believe that the asymptotic is correct, as I have checked with many functions and this is the only one I have found where the differences error fluctuates around zero and does not keep increasing / decreasing. Do you have any other candidate for $f(x)$? I am sure (because of differences error measurement) that $\log(x)>f(x)>\log\log(x)$

Comment: I agree with Alex Ravsky, the sum should be up to $k=n-1$. I checked the asymptotics numerically and I have some doubts on your claim. I rather find that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k/n) = O(n)$$ I checked only for $n<10^5$, the ratio seems bounded, spanning 8 orders of magnitude. This is incompatible with your proposed equivalent. Btw, $f(1/x)$ is not integrable on $(0,1)$ (problem at $1/e$), so Mason and mathlove's claims are false. The non integrability of $f(1/x)$ is "morally" consistent with my observations, as you would expect fluctuations larger than  for the values $k\sim n/e$.

Comment: @Juan Moreno : LPZ says "Mason and mathlove's claims are false". LPZ seems to think that our comments claim $\int_0^1\frac{\log(1/x)}{\log\log(1/x)}dx=0$. My comment (Mason's comment too, I think) does not claim that. My comment says that if $f(x)$ is such that $ \frac{n}{\log(n)}\sim \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$, then it is necessary that $\int_0^1 f(1/x)dx=0$.